# How can I convert the below xsd file to java file?

Tags: java, web-services, maven, xsd

plz help me to convert the below xsd into java code. I am using maven also.

![an xsd for login web service]

```
<xs:element name="loginRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="channel" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="username" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="password" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="loginResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="response" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Check out "wsimport" and "xjc"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xjc`, which comes with your Java development kit to create Java classes from an XML schema file. You can run this from the command line:

```
xjc schemafile.xsd
```

You'll have to wrap the  elements like this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <!-- your elements -->
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: can u plz provide some steps to use xjc ?

Comment: Running it from the command line is very simple, see the given command.

Comment: I ran the command, the java files are created in the below location
io\spring\guides\gs_producing_web_service\

Comment: You can influence that using some xjc options. Run `xjc -help` for details.